# In React, is it possible to freeze the parent row in a SyncFusion TreeGrid while scrolling thru the child rows?

Tags: reactjs, syncfusion

I'm using Syncfusion in our React application. For a particular page, we are using a TreeGrid component. When we expand a data row, is it possible to keep that expanded parent row frozen in place while we scroll thru the data in the child rows?

I've attached a screen shot. In this example, I expanded the "Interested" row to show the subrows beneath it. I'm trying to freeze the top "Interested" row while I scroll. We'd also want to be able to expand multiple parent rows (Interviewed, App Started, etc.), be able to scroll thru them with the parent row frozen, and when through all of each parent's children, go to the next parent row and freeze that one while we scroll the next set of children.

Does that make sense? Please let me know if this is possible, and if you have any questions. Thanks!

[sync table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkaz8.png)

Answer (score 0):

Query:  When we expand a data row, is it possible to keep that expanded parent row frozen in place while we scroll thru the data in the child rows?.

Currently, we don’t have support for freezing the parent rows while scrolling the child rows of the treegrid. And currently we don't have any plan to implement this feature.